# Internal Style Sheet basic issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a basic style sheet with a background, and a form in the middle.

With the code I have, the background shows but the form is not visible.  When all is said and done, the only HTML I will need will be text inside the form.  But for now, I need the form to display.  I am sure it is a mental error on my part, but here is the code:

```
   <head>

   <title>Basic Form</title>

   <style type="text/css">

     body 
     {
         background-image:url('images/background.png');
     }

     #main{ 
         background: url('/images/form.png') 0 0 no-repeat; 
         margin:250px auto; 
         z-index: 1; 
     }

     </head>


  <body>
       <div id="main">

      </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Give the `div` a width and height, or put some content in it and you should see the image.

Comment: I don't see a form in your code...

Comment: Check your z-index, remove z-index from #main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set any dimensions for #main, so the width and height are auto.

That div has no content, so the height becomes `0`.

With no height, there is no visible area to render a background image on.

Comment: You mean in the CSS tag?  Do i need any actual content inside my div tag for it to display?

Comment: You need to stop the height being zero. You can leave the CSS as it is and add content, or you can add a `height`, `min-height`, etc to the stylesheet.

Comment: Ok thanks!  Is it good practice to set a height in specific pixels with css?  The image does have specific dimensions, but wasn't sure if % based height/width was a better option?

Comment: *Generally* speaking, it is better to leave height at `auto` and let content increase the size of an element — otherwise the content might spill out of the element. `min-height` is useful.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see your div then you'd need to put something inside or give it a min-height.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `<div>` has no height (width is 100% by default), no background will show. You should simply insert your form or at least set a `min-height` on it.

Also, you forgot to close your `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not a typo the `<style>` tag should be closed inside the head.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Form

```
 body 
 {
     background-image:url('images/background.png');
 }

 #main{ 
     background: url('/images/form.png') 0 0 no-repeat; 
     margin:250px auto; 
     z-index: 1; 
 }
```